# What's the real type? NSString or NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsnumber

I have a NSDictionary that contains data converted from json data, like `{"message_id":21}`.
then I use `NSNumber *message_id = [dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"]` to get the data.

but when I use this `message_id`,

```
Message *message = [NSEntityDescription ....
message.messageId = message_id;
```

I got the runtime error, **assigning _NSCFString to NSNumber**,

so I have to use NSNumberFormatter to do the conversion.

```
NSString *messageId = [dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"];
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
message.messageId = [f numberFromString:messageId];
```

this code works.

but when I was debugging, I saw `message_id` of

```
NSNumber *message_id = [dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"]
```

has a valid value, 21.

Can anyone see the problem here?

Comment: Let's see the declaration of the `messageId` property on `Message`.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * messageId;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to save a NSString to a NSNumber. If you want it as an NSNumber you can do:

```
NSNumber *message_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"] intValue]];
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: what's wrong with this one? NSNumber *message_id = [dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"], variable message_id has a valid value

Comment: I can't say excactly why this doesn't work since I don't know the values in your dictionary. But my guess is that it returns a NSString object. Which will cause an error.

Comment: the dictionary contains value "21" for key "message_id". it's generated by JSONKit from a json string {"message_id":"21"}

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%@",  [dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"]). You will receive NSString or NSCFString. And you can't just put a NSString object in a NSNumber.

Comment: statement NSNumber *message_id = [dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"] doesn't throw any error, and the debug window show it's a NSNumber and value equals 21. but I got the error when doing assignment, message.messageId = message_id; says that cannot assign NSCFString to NSNumber

Comment: Yes. This is a bit hard to explain.. But valueForKey: returns an id object, so xcode won't be able to understand what's actually returned and assumes that you know what it is and allows you to put it into the NSNumber variable. When you set it in a property it verifies the type is a NSNumber. But since your valueForKey: returned a NSCFString, not a NSNumber it will give you an error.

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"] intValue]] - is overkill, point is [[dictionary valueForKey:@"message_id"]  - already NSNumer type

Answer (score 1):

What library are you using to do the conversion? {"message_id":21} means that an NSNumber with a value of 21 should be returned as an NSNumber, {"message_id":"21"} should return it as an NSString.

Using a number formatter is total overkill. Use the method "integerValue" which works just fine both with NSString* and with NSNumber* - you will get the integer 21, whether the object is NSString or NSNumber. The formatter code will obviously run into trouble if your object *is* an NSNumber and not an NSString.

So: message.messageId = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[messageId integerValue]];

I'd probably add a category to NSDictionary

- (NSNumber*)nsIntegerNumberForKey:(NSString*)key

which handles the situations where the key is not present, or where the value is a null value or a dictionary or array, so you can use it everywhere you need an NSNumber with an integer value from a JSON document and have error checking everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Read here [SAVING JSON TO CORE DATA](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/06/02/saving-json-to-core-data/) and [JSON official page](http://www.json.org/)

> The JSON standard is quite clear about how to distinguish strings from
>   numbers– basically, strings are surrounded by quotes and numbers are
>   not. JSON web services however, are not always good about following this requirement. And even when they are, they are not always consistent from one record to another.

So if you have receive NSNumber where NSString is preferred, you must inspect and fix yourself